# handle JSONP calls in ZEND

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, jsonp

couldn't find an answer via search (or google) so i'll ask it myself.
is it possible to handle JSONP calls to the zend framework?

only found this page:

http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Json_Server+-+Lode+Blomme

but i'm not sure if it is already implemented!?

thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is just a JSON response that is wrapped in a specified callback function that is executed on the client.

[Zend_Json_Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.server.html) is *only* for JSON-RPC at the moment.  The link you found is an archived (unimplemented) proposal to add JSONP support.

The good news is that *you don't need any sort of framework to support JSONP*.  Assuming `$response` is the data you wish to return to the user, and `$callback` [contains the **sanitized** callback](http://www.json-p.org/):

```
echo $callback, '(', json_encode($response), ');';
```

Tada, you've JSONP'd.

Please take care to read the document I linked about sanitizing the callback.  Failure to sanitize the callback may result in an exploitable condition.

Comment: hi charles. thanks for the quick reply.
i know that i don't have to use any framework, but what if i already am ... :)
will read the document about sanitizing and try to implement it using the zend framework. and will post if it worked. thx

Comment: finally had the time to check up on this - and it really works great.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

for those of you that are using ZEND framework and want to know what i had to change in order to get this working ...

had to make changes on a couple of files:

1) added a new layout under VIEWS > LAYOUTS called json.phtml

```
<?php  
    header('Content-type: application/javascript');  
    echo $this->layout()->content;  
?>
```

2) controller

added a new action called jsonAction

```
public function jsonAction()  
{
    $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('json');  

    $callback = $this->getRequest()->getParam('callback');
    if ($callback != "")
    {
        // strip all non alphanumeric elements from callback
        $callback = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $callback);
    }  
    $this->view->callback = $callback;  

    // ...  
}
```

3) added a new view under VIEWS > SCRIPTS > json.phtml

```
<?php  
if ($this->callback != "")  
{  
    echo $this->callback, '(', json_encode($response), ');';   
}  
else  
{  
    echo json_encode($response);  
}
?>
```

now i can make an ajax call via jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://<your_url>/<your_controller>/json',
    data: {},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error("+jqXHR+", "+textStatus+", "+errorThrown+")");
    }
});
```

maybe this helps someone ...