# Use Local JSON File for Databinding in SAPUI5

Tags: json, data-binding, sapui5

I have a little Problem with SAPUI5. I have the following Code:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.loadData("JSON/saplogon.json");


    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
        visibleRowCount: 30,
        firstVisibleRow: 0
    });


    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Server"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "Server"),
        width: "40%"
    }));


    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Beschreibung"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "Description"),
        width: "40%"
    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Adresse"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "Address"),
        width: "10%"
    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "SystemID"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "mssysname"),
        width: "10%"
    }));


    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    oTable.bindRows({
        path: "/Systeme",
        filter: allFilter
    });     

    oPage_Results.addContent(oTable);
```

the Code above works but when I change the directory of the .JSON File to a Directory on my Server it wont work, I have also tried to get the data from another Server with JSONP but that also wont work, can anybody please help me to find a way for consuming a local  JSON file from my server which is not in my package.

Thank you very much guys

Comment: You should check the url of the request that tries to load the json-file. For example a tomcat on my machine searches the file file at `http://localhost:8080/project/JSON/saplogon.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Ajax the file, after defining the table and its columns:

```
var sServiceUrl = 'yourServerOrNetworkPathInclJson';
var post = $.ajax({
            url : sServiceUrl,
            type : "GET"
        });

post.done(function(data) {

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    console.log(data); // check binding path
    oModel.setData(data);

    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    oTable.bindRows({
        path : "/", // might also be "/d/results" or whatever
    });
}
```

Comment: When i try it with your code snippet it tells me that Cross-Origin-Requests are blocked, but both scripts are hosted on the same server under the same domain.

Comment: hm I think this is also the reason why using loadData does not work, why dont you put the json locally into any eclipse folder? and then something like /json/yourfile.json would be the path ...

Comment: The problem is, the file is changing every week and is generated by an Abap Report so i would have download the file and upload it through my IDE and that would be not very clever

Comment: you dont have a SAP Netweaver Gateway right? loadData needs an gateway service method - why dont you pull the json via javascript? method woudl be load() ... or check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478985/jquery-ajax-loads-jsonp-from-localhost-but-doesnt-return-data or that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file

Answer (score 2):

Better way of loading the JSON file in UI5

```
var oModel = new JSONModel()
oModel.loadData(pathToTheJSONFile);
oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(oEventModel){
    //console.log(oModel.getData());
    //This is called after data is loading
});
oTable.setModel(oModel);
```

i feel this is better way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked now, i just installed an IIS7 Webserver on the server of my SAP ERP System and hosted my file over the IIS7. I didnt needed to use an AJAX request or something the normal load model method of the SAPUI5 library worked. Thanks for your help mates.